# Ecto schema belongs_to association using two fields

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have two models: `Auction` and `Artwork`. An `Artwork` `belongs_to` an `Auction`.

This is set-up against an external db, so the migrations are not handled by Ecto and the fields are camelcased in the underlying  db.

The issue I am running into is that the association is done via two fields (a tuple association): `token_id` and `contract_address`.

Neither `token_id` nor `contract_address` are unique, however as a tuple they are unique.

This is the `Auction` schema:

```
@primary_key {:auction_id, :id, source: :auctionId}
schema "auction" do
  field :token_id, :integer, source: :tokenId
  field :contract_address, :string, source: :contractAddress
  
  # ideally would want to do something like this
  belongs_to :artwork, Foundation.Artworks.Artwork,
    references: [:contract_address, :token_id]

end
```

And then the `Artwork` schema:

```
@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, []}
schema "artwork" do
  field :name, :string
  field :description, :string
  field :token_id, :integer, source: :tokenId
  field :contract_address, :string, source: :contractAddress
end
```

How could I approach this so that the `Artwork` is associated using both fields?

Answer (score 0):

Does it works for you:

```elixir
@primary_key false
schema "artwork" do
  field :name, :string
  field :description, :string
  field :token_id, :integer, source: :tokenId, primary_key: true
  field :contract_address, :string, source: :contractAddress, primary_key: true
end
```